# Absolute continuity for non-measures?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Let $B$ be the collection of Borel subsets of $R^2$.

A measure on $B$ is said to be *absolutely continuous with respect to area* if any subset with area 0 has measure 0.

**Is there a natural generalization of absolute continuity, for functions on $B$ which are *not* measures?**

am looking for a property which describes those functions on $B$ which change "smoothly". For example, if $m$ is a function on $B$, then the value of $m$ on a square changes continuously as the square grows, i.e.:  $m([0,t]\times[0,t])$ is a continuous function of $t$. The same holds for other shapes, i.e. $m(circle\ centered\ at\ origin\ with\ radius\ t)$ is a continuous function of $t$.

A measure having this property which I am looking for, will also be [I think] absolutely continuous by the usual definition.

I would like say simply that $m$ is a *continuous* function on $B$, but I didn't find a definition of continuity for functions on Borel sets.

Comment: "Other shapes" is difficult to get a handle on. Borel sets can be extremely complicated. If $m$ is not a measure, it will be tough to approximate these things by "nice" Borel sets.

Comment: To study continuity you need some topology ! For instance You can topologize $B$ using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_metric.

Comment: @MarcinMalogrosz so a function $m$ on $B$ can be considered continuous, if it assigns similar values to subsets with a small Hausdorff distance? Does this imply the standard definition of absolute continuity when $m$ is a measure?